# How to get the data in HTML format while using the each function in Cheerio

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, dom, cheerio

I am trying

```
$("iframe").each(function (_i, link) {
    const data = cheerio.html(link)
})
// output : <iframe id="iframe"></iframe>
```

It gives me the data of the tag only.
But I want the whole data in HTML format which is present inside the iFrame tag.

eg : `<html><body><h1>hello world</h1></body></html>`

Comment: It would just be `$('#iframe').html()` however iframes usually have a src that they load content from, and that won't be there with cheerio.

Comment: @pguardiario i want to manipulate the iframe using the cheerio and change the data inside the iframe. is it possible ?

Comment: Not if it comes from src, cheerio won't load it.

Answer (score 0):

You can only get it if it's on the same domain because of XSS-protection.

This is the code to use:

```
$('#iframe').contents().find("html").html();
```

This will return all the html in your iframe.
Instead of .find("html") you can use any selector you want such as:

```
.find('body')
```

or

```
.find('div#mydiv')
```

You can also do it with JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML
```

But again, this won't work if the iframe document is hosted on another domain or same domain but different port number, because of XSS-protection.

Comment: ` $("iframe").each(function (_i, link) {
  
        console.log($(link).contents().find("html").html());
    });`

returning null @Timothy Alexis Vass